# Java Static object/method issue

Tags: java, class, static

I got a question about how to use static, I saw a sample:

```
public class Exe {
    static int i = 47;
    public void call() {
        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            if (i == 2) {
                System.out.println("\n");
            }
        }
    }

    public Exe() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Exe t1 = new Exe();
        Exe t2 = new Exe();
        t2.i = 60;
        System.out.println(t1.i);
        t1.call();
        System.out.println(t2.i);
        t2.call();
    }
}
```

When I tried to run it, it printed 60 3, I am wondering why t2.i here is 3, I do not know where the 3 comes from, also, the both results of t1.call() and t2.call() were not printed, please advise, thank you!

Comment: Man, you should format the code snippets properly, this one is not readable!

Comment: The results of `t1.call()` and `t2.call()` probably were printed. They would be blank lines. If you post the output, we could see.

Comment: If the `static` keyword is giving you issues, try this.  Start a new project, take out the `static` keyword, but leave everything else the same, then run it.  Compre the output from one to the other and see if that helps clear the issue up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`static` means that every instance of the class has access to the same, single instance of the variable.

When you create `t1`, `t1.i` is initialized to `47`.  Then you create `t2`.  `t2.i` and `t1.i` are the same variable, so whether you do `t1.i = 60` or `t2.i = 60`, they're BOTH equal to `60`.

So before you do `t1.call();` or `t2.call()`, the first thing you do is print out `t1.i`, which is `60`, as per the line `t1.i = 60;`.

Then you run `t1.call()` which runs through the `for` loop.  The `for` loop exits when `i` can't pass the test `i < 3`, and since `i` is an integer, this happens as soon as `i` is incremented to `3`.

After you've run `t1.call()`, `i` is now equal to `3`.  This means both `t1.i` and `t2.i` since `static` means there's only one copy of `i` across all instances of the `Exe` class here.  So you print out `t2.i` and it is equal to `3`, as it should be.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Does it mean that the call of t1.call() change the value of i?

Comment: Yes.  Because for the `for` loop in the `call()` method of your `Exe` class uses the variable `i`, the loop re-initializes `i` to 0.  And the `static` keyword mean that `t1.i` and `t2.i` refer to the same variable.

Answer (score 2):

```
for(i=0; i<3;i++){
    if(i==2){
        System.out.println("\n");
    }
}
```

Your static variable **Assigned/incremented** here.

Not the *i* (which you are assuming, it's different) in **for** loop.

To clear the clouds, Just take another variable called `j` and do the looping.

```
for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    if (j == 2) {
        System.out.println("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 This is where using a debugger would have answered the question

Comment: There isn't any `i` "in the `for` loop"; there's only the one `i` anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

The `3` comes from your `for` loop, which is reusing the same `static int i` that you're manually setting to `60` before you call `call()`. The results of the `println` probably *are* being printed, but they're just blank lines.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
```

In this statement instead of treating i as a local variable it is taken to be class variable which you defined. As for class variables only one copy is maintained for all the instance after the for loop finished(i=3) value of you class variable i remains to be 3.

Answer (score 0):

Your static variable is the same across all objects, this is an effect of `static`. This means that when you call `t2.i = 60;` both t1.i and t2.i are set equal to 60. Then when you call `t1.call();` you again change both objects. As others have explained your for loop is setting the variable i = 3.

It's because it's a static variable that the assignment affects both objects

Answer (score 0):

Static members doesn't reflect the object state!

All objects of a class will have the same copy(mean to say same value) of the static variables. If one object changes the value of a static variable, since the static variable holds the same value across all the objects, the static variable value will be updated across all the objects of that class. This rule reflects your result.

See the below example:

```
public class StaticTest {

    static int staticA = 10;

    int intA;

    public StaticTest(int intA){
        this.intA = intA;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StaticTest test1 = new StaticTest(10);
        System.out.println(test1.intA);
        System.out.println(test1.staticA);
        StaticTest test2 = new StaticTest(20);
        System.out.println(test2.intA);
        System.out.println(test2.staticA);
    }
}
```

Below is the outpput:

10
10
20
10